# How do I validate a normal method as if it were a CDI InjectionPoint?

Tags: java, cdi, weld, weld-se

I'm building a simple API framework on top of Weld CDI and Undertow, to get familiar with the CDI Portable Extension programming model. It's a strict subset of JAX-RS:

```
@Default
@Path("/dogs")
public class Dogs {
   @Inject
   private MyService service;

   @GET
   public Response get(@HeaderParam("DogDebug") String debugParam, @Inject DebugService debugger) {  return BLAH; }

   @Path("/{id}")
   @GET
   public Response getById(@PathParam("id") String param) {  return BLAH; }
}
```

My CDI Portable Extension collects up all the AnnotatedTypes that have the Path annotation. When CDI finishes booting, an Undertow webserver starts and all the collected types (and their paths) are registered with an Undertow RoutingHandler.

The Extension is responsible for building HttpHandlers for each method that's annotated with @GET/@POST etc...

```
    public HttpHandler getHandler(AnnotatedMethod<?> producer) {
            Object contextualHandler = manager.createInstance()
                    .select(producer.getDeclaringType().getJavaClass()).get();
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(contextualHandler, "Could not obtain a contextual reference to a handler for this");
            Object result = producer.getJavaMember().invoke(contextualHandler);

            Response response;
            if(!(result instanceof Response)) {
                response = Response.ok(result).build();
            } else {
                response = (Response) result;
            }
            response.write(exchange);
    }
```

As you can see, right now the handler is using plain-ol Java Reflection to call the resource method.

I'd like to make method parameter injection work, as shown in my example above. I can use the BeanManager and metadata to grab the right parameters when actually running the handler, but ...

How can I validate the injection point? i.e. with an AnnotatedType I got from a ProcessAnnotatedType event, how can I validate an *arbitrary method* as if it were a producer or Constructor or event observer?

Update: So far, I've gotten pretty far with the [InjectableMethod](https://deltaspike.apache.org/javadoc/1.6.1/org/apache/deltaspike/core/util/metadata/builder/InjectableMethod.html) class from Deltaspike. It inspects the method and creates an InjectionPoint that can be passed to BeanManager.validate. However, it doesn't have much usage in the publicly Googleable code of the world.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use jax-rs?

Comment: It's a fun exercise to build up a web framework - all those reference implementations had to start _somewhere_.

Comment: Oh, yes it is for that reason I agree. Adding that in the question initially might get you more help though. On the other hand, watch out it does not get into production.. I'm currently in the process of phasing out 3 of these internally since former colleagues... well... you get the point.. Hell of a job...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then [BeanManager#createInjectionPoint(AnnotatedParameter)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html#createInjectionPoint-javax.enterprise.inject.spi.AnnotatedParameter-) is what you're looking for in terms of creating and validating the injection points. No need for DeltaSpike or other implementation specifics, it's already part of the spec.